# Jade interpolation within javascript

Tags: pug, scalatra, scalate

(Note, this is the Scalate Jade, if that makes a difference)

I have the following route:

```
get("/fruit") {
  contentType = "text/html"
  jade("fruity", "fruit" -> "apple")
}
```

And this `fruity.jade` template:

```
-@ val fruit: String

p Alerting #{fruit}
:javascript
  alert("#{fruit}");
```

It renders like so:

```
<body><p>Alerting apple</p>
<script type="text/javascript">
  //<![CDATA[
    alert("#{fruit}");
  //]]>
</script>
</body>
```

The `fruit` value is not interpolated for the javascript portion. How can I get it to resolve in javascript?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found that `:&javascript` or `:!javascript` will work. It is explained [here](http://scalate.github.io/scalate/documentation/jade-syntax.html#Filter_Interpolation).

Comment: Very interesting! I don't think it's supported in the official compiler, however

Comment: FYI, [here](http://scalate.github.io/scalate/documentation/jade-syntax.html#Filter_Interpolation) is an updated document link (original no longer seems to be working).

Answer (score 1):

If filters are not interpolated, just use a raw `:script` tag.